# Server fails to upload large files with gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, large-files

I made a small server with flask to upload files (and then do stuff with them). The upload is through and HTML form that sends a file:

```
<form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

On the server side I do the following:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if 'file' in request.files:
        f = request.files['file']
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], werkzeug.secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(file_path)

    return 'File is being uploaded'
```

It works fine for small files but on large files, it fails. The problem is that if I run the script manually not through gunicorn `python main.py` I can upload files that I couldn't before. I thought I needed to change the max size in gunicorn but couldn't find how to do it.

I also thought to use a stream and then write chunks but again, I couldn't find how to access the stream with flask.

Thanks for your help

Comment: "It works fine for small files but on large files, it fails." In what way?

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to timeout problem. By default, gunicorn will hang if a process takes more than 30 seconds. The time to upload a large file can easily exceed this amount. You might want to specify a custom timeout value when you start gunicorn. For example if you want to set timeout to 300 seconds: `exec gunicorn [app]:[app] --timeout 300`

Source: [gunicorn timeout setting](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout)