# Upload stops after 30 seconds, eventually getting timeout (with nginx, gunicorn, flask)

Tags: javascript, python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

### Goal

I am making my own online server and recently added a feature enabling me to upload files and see the progress. I am building everything with Flask, Gunicorn and Nginx, pure CSS & JS.

### Problem

However, when I try to upload large files (i.e. takes more than 30s to process), it freezes at 30 seconds of upload, then unfreezes at around 1min and freezes again 5 seconds later until 3.5 min where I get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. I just don't know how to fix that and I've been working on it for hours now.

### What I've tried

- Using `gevent` workers for Gunicorn. I tried everything below **with and without** `gevent` workers.
- Running `gunicorn` with `--log-level debug --keep-alive 30 --timeout 300 --graceful-timeout 300`.  Nothing changed. Nothing gets shown in debug when trying to upload.
- I added `proxy_connect_timeout 300s;`, `proxy_read_timeout 300s;` and `client_max_body_size 100G;` in the `http` section of my `nginx.conf` file just in case.

I also read all these posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69720981/djangogunicornnginx-upload-large-file-connection-reset-error), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677478/nginx-django-gunicorn-large-file-uploads-stalled-after-30-seconds), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816215/110-connection-timed-out-nginx-gunicorn), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855197/frequent-worker-timeout), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588938/djangogunicornnginx-upload-large-file-502-error) and more, but none of these fixes worked. I'm helpless!

### Relevant code if needed

Upload function:

```js
function uploadFile(path) {
    let formdata = new FormData();
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let filesize = document.getElementById("fileInput").files[0].size;

    formdata.append("fileinput", document.getElementById("fileInput").files[0]);

    req.upload.addEventListener('progress', (uploadEvent) => {
        let progressElem = document.getElementById('progressIndicator');

        if (uploadEvent.loaded < filesize) {
            progressElem.innerHTML = (100 * uploadEvent.loaded / filesize).toFixed(2) + '%';
        } else {
            progressElem.style.color = "green";
            progressElem.innerHTML = "✅ File uploaded";
        }
    });

    req.open("POST", path);
    req.send(formdata);
}
```

`views.py`:

```py
@app.route("/files/<path:path>", methods=["POST", "GET"]):
def files(path):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if not utils.is_uploader(str(session.get("session")), sessions) or os.path.isfile(BASE_DIR + path):
            return '', 403

        if not os.path.exists(BASE_DIR + path):
            return '', 404

        file = request.files.get("fileinput")
        if not file: return redirect(url_for("/files" + path)), 400

        secured_filename = secure_filename(file.filename or '')
        if secured_filename == '':
            return redirect(url_for("/files" + path)), 400

        file.save(os.path.join(BASE_DIR + path, secured_filename))

        return '', 204

    # rest not included
```

Comment: Just a random comment; if you are not afraid to debug - I'd personally start be eliminating nginx from front of gunicorn and let gunicorn serve also the static assets so that you can atleast narrow things a bit .. does gunicorn have setting for timeout  ? There was this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868863/server-fails-to-upload-large-files-with-gunicorn which could be related

Comment: @rasjani yes gunicorn has a timeout option, which I tried with `--timeout 300`. No success. I really don't know what to do now. However, bypassing nginx and trying to serve directly on localhost seems a good idea; I doubt the problem comes from nginx though.

Comment: i wouldn't rule out nginx with default settings out yet.. I have faint recollection i've had somewhat similar issues with $httpd server proxy passing stuff to actual service.